# Restrict a CONTAINSTABLE search to avoid searching whole table

Tags: sql, full-text-search

Hi I am doing a search on a column of a table using CONTAINSTABLE.
The issue is the performance.
This is my query:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM dbo.Document d
INNER JOIN dbo.DocuemntVehicleXRef vx ON (vx.DocuemntID = d.DocumentID)
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE (Document , QueryContent , @searchterm ) ftt ON ( d.DocumentID = ftt.[Key] )  
WHERE vx.VehicleId = @vehicleId
```

So to improve the performance(since the Document table is huge). I would need to do the CONTAINSTABLE function, instead of over all the dbo.Docuemnt table, only over the Documents bounded to the VehicleId (since the rest of the searches are unnecessarily)
Is there a workaround or a way to do this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to create multiple indexed views that each return a subset of the documents.  Each view gets its own ft index, and you manage the query logic to only select from the relevant views.  This approach works good if your table is easy to split into commonly used chunks, such as a hierarchical category structure.

Another approach is to "muck" with the indexed text by appending a unique key. for example, "VEHICLEID001"  Then you can search for "VEHICLEID001" in addition to the other keywords.    This approach is frowned upon by Microsoft as an anti-practice, but does work.

Comment: Sorry for the revival of this old question, but do you have a source for this being an anti-pratice? I found this article from 2007 which suggests using embedded filters: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc917695.aspx#Embedding_Filter

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721269.aspx#_Toc202506250 In the section on performance improvements.  "In SQL Server 2000 and 2005, a valid workaround for some scenarios (where the relational cardinality was far lower than the full-text one) was to push the content of the relational columns into the full-text index, ..."